# Python Script Read TXT and create new

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this script for creating 'acl' to add all IP's of server to squid config

```
file = open("ip.txt", "r")
ip_list = [line for line in file]

for acl, tcp in zip(ip_list[::2], ip_list[1::2]):
    print "acl ip" + str(ip_list.index(acl) + 1) + " myip " + acl.strip()
    print  "tcp_outgoing_address " + tcp.strip() + " ip" + str(ip_list.index(acl) + 1)
```

My problem is that when script read IP from ip.txt I need to enter 2 times the same IP cause I need the same IP 2 times in my final paste.

My friend told me to create double loop but I have no idea how to do it.

ip.txt looks like this

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Final paste should looked like this

```
acl ip1 myip 1.1.1.1
tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 ip1
acl ip2 myip 2.2.2.2
tcp_outgoing_address 2.2.2.2 ip2
acl ip3 myip 3.3.3.3
tcp_outgoing_address 3.3.3.3 ip3
acl ip4 myip 4.4.4.4
tcp_outgoing_address 4.4.4.4 ip4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do that, without the overhead of `zip()` and `index()`:

```
file = open("ip.txt", "r")

for index, line in enumerate(file):
    print("acl ip" + str(index + 1) + " myip " + line.strip())
    print("tcp_outgoing_address " + line.strip() + " ip" + str(index + 1))
```

even nicer (i think):

```
file = open("ip.txt", "r")

tpl = """acl ip{index} myip {ip}
tcp_outgoing_address {ip} ip {index}"""

for index, line in enumerate(file):
    print(tpl.format(index=index, ip=line.strip()))
```

and the output will be the same that you request:

> acl ip1 myip 1.1.1.1
>   tcp_outgoing_address 1.1.1.1 ip1
>   acl ip2 myip 2.2.2.2
>   tcp_outgoing_address 2.2.2.2 ip2
>   acl ip3 myip 3.3.3.3
>   tcp_outgoing_address 3.3.3.3 ip3

Comment: thank you for your contribution your script is great

Answer (score 0):

I've made also this with input from user and saving to TXT

```
file1 = open("iplist.txt","w") 

ip = raw_input("Enter IP list:").split(" ")

tpl = """acl ip{index} myip {ip}
tcp_outgoing_address {ip} ip{index}
"""

for index, line in enumerate(ip):
    file1.write(tpl.format(index=index, ip=line.strip()))
```